# Насколько быстрее будет запрос Mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

В таблице около миллиона записей.
Можно сделать несколько запросов на выборку строк с использованием **WHERE** по индексам:

1. `WHERE type = ... , idUser = ..., idTouser = ... ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20`
2. `WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4,5...)`
3. `WHERE type = ... , idUser = ..., idTouser = ...AND time > last_time_selected ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20`

Какой будет оптимальный и при каких условиях? Где можно почерпнуть информацию?

Comment: Явное перечисление всех id поможет, только если их два-три, если там их десятки, то такой запрос будет медленный, очень медленный. 1 и 3 запросы похожие, но отличаются только дополнительным условием. Поэтому, часто, один правильный индекс может сильно улучшить производительность.

Comment: @KoVadim, 200к записей. id in(<1000 значений>):  
Запрос открыт за 0,016c [0,003c выполнение, 0,013c выборка]  
explain тоже ничего удивительного не показывает simple, range, PRIMARY...
так что просьба аргументировать с примерами.

Comment: И это называется быстро? Или теперь медленно, если полчаса? А если приложение нагруженное? Это в лучшем случае 67 запросов (не учитывая других накладных расходов).

Собственно, Вы сами и аргументировали.

Потестируйте с другими запросами, сравните, только не забывайте, мускуль научился хорошо кешировать запросы даже в самых неочевидных ситуациях.

Comment: Буду тестировать - результаты выложу чуть позже...

Comment: @KoVadim, При чем тут нагруженное, не нагруженное? если идет 67 запросов на один реквест, это говорит не в пользу выбранной структуры приложения только и всего.

>  только если их два-три, если там их десятки, то такой запрос будет медленный, очень медленный

вот это ваше утверждение ложно.  
И я специально для вас уже протестировал. 3 тысячных секунды на список из тысячи значений (это еще надо поискать где такое может понадобится). Вы сказали что будет супер медленно если там будут десятки значений. Не будет. Или вы посмотрели на 0.013? так это на передачу данных время.

Comment: В данном случае надо смотреть на конкретном примере. У этих алгоритмов разные схемы работы, у которых в зависимости от данных разная вычислительная сложность. В какой-то момент один из них начнет превосходить над другим. 

---------

Но @KoVadim правильно говорит, что IN с возрастанием в нем данных будет работать медленнее, так как в его реализации идет двойной цикл сравнения элементов и единственный плюс, индекс это сгладит. В первом же случае простое сравнение с отбрасыванием, но в минус может сказываться сортировка выбранных данных ORDER BY. В общем, тестируйте, однозначного ответа тут нет

Comment: expr IN (value,...)

Returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else returns 0. If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a binary search. This means IN is very quick if the IN value list consists entirely of constants. Otherwise, type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the arguments.

Как-то так. Хочу бенчей

Comment: Под рукой только работающая БД в MSSQL с таблицей статистики на 300000+ записей. Если интересно кому, вот результаты:

> WHERE ID_STAT IN(1000 values), план: Вложенные циклы, Время(среднее для 2 попыток): 124 мс

> WHERE ID_STAT IN(10000 values), план: соединение слиянием + сортировка значений IN, время(среднее для 3 попыток): 458 мс

> WHERE ID_STAT IN(50000 values), план: хеш соединение, время(среднее для 7 попыток): 2555 мс

Comment: > WHERE CODE="7", план: простой CLUSTER SCAN, время 495мс, 150000 строк возвращено

> WHERE USERNAME = '%username%' AND CODE = 7, план: простой CLUSTER SCAN, время 325мс, 5757 строк возвращено

При дальнейшем добавление AND или OR + разные сочетания, время поиска просто сокращается на несколько мс, диапазон от 500мс до 200мс, план запроса без изменений.

Comment: @Alex Krass, вы считаете время выдачи данных, а не выполнения запроса. Если вы сделаете просто select * from ваша таблица он будет висеть сутки и вы скажете это in работает плохо? Ваши тесты хороши, конечно, но чтоб сравнивать их в идеале, надо, чтоб они возвращали одни и те же данные. Именно так как указано в вопросе.  
Цитата ваша подтверждает, что in будет летать, если там константы.  
Кроме того, по первичному ключу (кластерному индексу) выборка будет идти в общем случае (за оччч редкими исключениями) гораздо быстрее, чем по составным (тем более) индексам, если они возвращают одно и то же

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,
Это моя цитата. У меня вот возник вопрос.  
Как я вижу из поста ТС'а, требуется фильтрация минимум по трем доменам. Вот и интересно, если же отфильтровать через три вызова IN() и получить идентичный результат, после сравнить время этой выборки и время выборки через сравнение, то какая будет разница?

Дело в том, что в одном из бенчей было видно, что операции сравнения целого типа (больше, меньше; равно - не проверялось) работают медленнее операций сравнения TIMESTAMP, как было сказано автором, видимо, из-за особенностей реализации.

Хочу бенч (1)